# Class resolution quirk with 'implements'

Tags: php, php-5.4

Can someone explain the following, seems like a bug to me.

```
<?php

class A implements JsonSerializable {
    public function jsonSerialize() { return []; }
}

new A();
new B();
new C();

class B {}
class C implements JsonSerializable {
    public function jsonSerialize() { return []; }
}
```

Has the following result

```
$ php test.php

Fatal error: Class 'C' not found in test2.php on line 9
```

Comment: new B(); is called before class B and that obviously not find

Comment: Define the class before calling it? If the engine doesn't force it normally, it's certainly a better design pattern.

Comment: Yeah I've resolved my question myself - the documentation says "Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement)."

The issue I was finding was when I removed the implements statement it worked calling it before defining it => the some cases its required part of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, move the instantiation after the class definition. PHP doesn't find any class B at line 8.

Answer (score 0):

> Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement).

When using implements it's a requirement - hence why it works without the implements statement.